# apply count on inner join in sql using sequelize

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

If i have Posts model and Likes model that PostsLikes model has postID as foreign key

How to create orm sequelize query to get post by id and number of likes on it

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery in `attributes` options like this:

```js
const posts = await Posts.findByPk(postId, {
  attributes: {
   include: [[Sequelize.literal('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PostsLikes where PostsLikes.postID = Posts.ID)'), 'LikesCount']]
  }
})
```